# DatePicker DIalog Is Not Showing?

Tags: java, android

```
2018-11-12 12:35:14.023 6711-6711/com.eventostrings E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.eventostrings.NewRSVPActivity has leaked window DecorView@15fe5c2[] that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:485)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
    at com.eventostrings.NewRSVPActivity.OpenSelectToDateDialog(NewRSVPActivity.java:1450)
    at com.eventostrings.NewRSVPActivity.lambda$onCreate$31(NewRSVPActivity.java:902)
    at com.eventostrings.-$$Lambda$NewRSVPActivity$uOaJ876ZssWsbvKcz2fht6cunQI.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**When I Call datePickerDialog.show(); is Throw Error Like**

How To Solve This Problem in NAdroid Studio ?

Comment: Please add exception into your question.

Comment: What error throwing ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added

Comment: Is Not Working.